# How can i implement a Linked List and another class

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I have a LinkedList class that i wrote and i have another class of Students. Each student has an ID,Name,GPA......

How can i add these variables to a linked list as 1 element. As if i need to search for an element in that linked list, i can show all the info of that student.

If you need further explanation, ill copy some code.

Comment: Please do so, but basically each node should have that information, for example a node would have: {nextNode, id, name, gpa, ...} Or if you want, {nextNode, element} in which an element could be a student.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the java.util.List example:

```
List<Student> roster = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Just substitute your own reference and implementation classes:

```
YourLinkedList roster = new YourLinkedList();
Student s = new Student();
roster.add(s);
```

As for the searching for a given Student instance, I'd write an Iterator that could take a Comarator and return a filtered version of your linked list.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have `Student` and `MyLinkedList` classes and now you want to use them, because maybe your linked list just support integer items. You can use something like this

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Now you need to add the `Student` class as the info for the nodes in your linked list:

```
public class MyLinkedList {
    class MyNode {
        private Student student;
        private MyNode next;
        public MyNode(Student student) {
            this.student = student;
            this.next = null;
        }
        public Student getStudent() {
            return this.student;
        }
    }
    private MyNode root;
    private int size;
    public MyLinkedList {
        this.root = null;
    }
    public void add(Student student) {
        //this is just one way to implement the insert method
        //you can rewrite to use your own implementation
        MyNode node = new MyNode(student);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
        } else {
            MyNode currentNode = root;
            while (currentNode.next != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            currentNode.next = node;
        }
        size++;
    }
    public void printData() {
        //method used to print the content of the linked list
        MyNode currentNode = root;
        while (currentNode != null) {
            Student student = currentNode.getStudent();
            System.out.println("Id: " + student.getId + " Name: " + student.getName());
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you implement a new linked list using a `Student` class. Let's try the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyLinkedList mll = new MyLinkedList;
    Student student;
    student = new Student();
    student.setId(1);
    student.setName("Luiggi");
    mll.add(student);
    student = new Student();
    student.setId(2);
    student.setName("Mendoza");
    mll.add(student);
    mll.printData();
}
```

This is just a sample, you can improve the code, but you get the main idea.